# Excel VBA and C# DLL: Instantiate WinForms Object can only be done once. At second try there is an error

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, interop, vba

I have built a C# dll containing a Winform. I want to open the Form from Excel VBA. The first try is always successful. It opens and does all the things I want it to do. Then I close it using the upper right red X.

When I try to open it a second time I always get the error message:
**"SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application."** Source: System.Windows.Forms

The WinForms class is a standard generated class by Visual Studio. I instantiate it in a different class:

```
namespace Schnittstellenvererbung
{
    [ComVisible(true), Guid("5D16EABF-B89F-45A1-8E4D-ACFAA084BF6F")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface ISchnittstellenvererbung
    {
        string ShowForm1();
    }

    [ComVisible(true), Guid("6A9EF0BB-BFF3-456E-B025-CB6A25F81F59")]
    [ProgId("Test.SchnittstellenvererbungExecuteProgram")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class ExecuteProgram : ISchnittstellenvererbung
    {
        public string ShowForm1()
        {
           try
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Form1 Oberflaeche;
                Oberflaeche = new Form1();
                Oberflaeche.ShowDialog();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message + e.Source);
            }

            return "Done";
        }
    }
}
```

In Excel VBA the call is pretty simple:

```
Sub test()

    Dim y As String
    Dim x As New Schnittstellenvererbung.ExecuteProgram

    y = x.ShowForm1

End Sub
```

When I close Excel and reopen it, it works again on the first try, but again the second try fails.

I wonder why this error appears, because the method SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault is always called before intantiating the form.

Ideas?

Comment: maybe this can help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/26960a4c-040a-40b4-baea-15adc275b44c/setcompatibletextrenderingdefault-must-be-called-before-the-first-iwin32window-object-is-created-in?forum=winforms

Comment: Also dont forget to dispose Overflaeche. The GC does funny things if you dont and I would not be suprised if it would be part of the problem

Comment: Might be that it is Part of the problem, but disposing does not solve the issue. I added the close and dispose command to the function. Just for testing:

Comment: I added the close and dispose command to the function:  `Oberflaeche.ShowDialog(); Oberflaeche.Close(); Oberflaeche.Dispose();`

Comment: @GuidoG: May you explain me how the link in your first comment can help me? I cannot see the correspondence to this issue.

Comment: The title of the article is exactly the error you where getting and the article tries to find a solution. So it seemed to me it could be of any use to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in the msdn. The Windows Form runs in a seperate Thread. The example code is VB, but it's not difficult to convert to C#. If anybody  needs help it can be converted with teleriks code converter.

Links:

MSDN Solution: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229591%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Code Converter: http://converter.telerik.com/